# Google App Engine - Transfer Application From A Closed Account To Another

Tags: google-app-engine, google-account

Is it possible to transfer an application from a closed Google account to a new Google account?

Comment: Can you still login to the closed account?

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to do this. You should contact the GAE support team in case they will be able to help you on this.